# Retrieving URL that caused redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm curious about something I will be working on with in the next couple days. If we're using IronPort where i work and an end user attempts to get on a site that is blocked. Now what im going to be doing is redirecting them to a cleaner page instead of the default built into IronPort. which allow them to make a request to have the page unblocked for valid reason or log in as different user. Now if i need to post the current URL that caused this redirect with Http.Cobtext.current.request.url  wont that return the URL of the redirected page instead of the page that caused the redirect. When my default page loads that says Sorry page cant be displayed and i pull request.url wont it give me my default page instead of previous url that caused redirect.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the referrer?

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
```

This may not be provided by all browsers for redirects though.

Comment: not familiar with how UrlReferrer works, but im doing a little reading now...new to the field programming, still finishing up school, so theres quite a bit of properties ive never used before

Comment: It should read the HTTP_REFERER server variable, which is supplied by the client. It may work for you, give it a go. :)